# Macro with optional parameter returning calculated length

Tags: macros, lengths, optional-arguments

I'm trying to define a macro returning a calculated length, but making the parameter optional breaks the macro (error `Missing number, treated as zero.`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{numprint}

\newcommand{\testa}[1]{\fpeval{#1*0.03}\linewidth}
\newcommand{\testb}[1][1]{\fpeval{#1*0.03}\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\lenprint[pt]{\testa{1}}% prints 10,34958 pt

\lenprint[pt]{\testa{2}}% prints 20,69915 pt

\lenprint[pt]{\testb}% gives ERROR and prints 0.030 pt

\lenprint[pt]{\testb[2]}% gives ERROR and prints 0.060 pt

\end{document}
```

Can you help understand why?

Is there a way to make the parameter optional without breaking the working macro?

N.B. The above MWE uses `\lenprint`, but I'm asking for a solution working in general or at least with `\addtolength`, since my real world need is to use the macro as argument of `\addtolength`.

Comment: A command with an optional argument is not fully expandable, a required feature if you want to use it in the argument to `\lenprint`.

Comment: @egreg Is there a way to make the parameter optional without breaking the working macro?

Comment: Very short answer: no.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `\testb` as expandable macro. For example:

```
\long\def\testb#1{\ifx[#1\afterfi{\testbA[}\else\afterfi{\testbA[1]#1}\fi}
\def\testbA[#1]{\fpeval{#1*0.03}\linewidth}
\long\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
```

It will not work in all cases but your case works:

```
\lenprint[pt]{\testb}% works

\lenprint[pt]{\testb[2]}% works
```

Comment: Just by chance; `\lenprint` does `\setlength{\@tempdima}{#2}` and so you get `\@tempdima=\testb\relax` which works because there is a token after `\testb` that can be taken as the argument. But it's ***very*** specific and other usages of `\testb` will definitely break.

Comment: And it works also for my real world need which is using the macro as argument of `\addtolenght`, so thanks.